Vitest how to mock callback?
I have the function inside my VUE 3 composition api file;
`const confirmAndLogin = () => {
  AuthServices.getConfirmationCode(
    email,
    (bindData: IAuthenticationCallback) => {
      data = bindData
    },
    () => {
      label = 'Email sent.'
      function()
    },
    (error: Error) => {
  label = 'Unable to send email.'
      function()
    }
  )
}`

Looked through the documentation, not sure tbh

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
